# Accessing localhost from android device

Tags: android

I am trying to test an android app that access data from an asp script running on internet information server. What is the URL to access the asp script output from the device. http://10.0.2.2 works for emulator but I need to test on device

Answer (score 1):

The device and the server (in this case, your computer) must be on the same network. 
You need to know the server IP and use it instead of 10.0.2.2.

How to get your computer IP address:

**Linux:** 
Type `ifconfig` on terminal

**Windows:**
Type `ipconfig` on the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I use this trick to deploy apk's wirelessly to my device from Android Studio, with IIS. Just go on your computer, open a command prompt, type `ipconfig` and see what your local network IP address is. Type that exact IP address into your phone and forward-slash into your asp page.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great I'm going to try this